# Reselect objects from list that I stored in avariable

Tags: scripting

I'm very new to scripting in Blender.
How do I reselect a list of objects that I have previously stored in a variable?

```
import bpy

# Create a variable that stores the currently selected objects
sel_Objs = bpy.context.selected_objects

# Now deselect everything
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# Now select an object called 'Cone'
bpy.data.objects['Cone'].select_set(True)
```

How would I now reselect the objects stored in the sel_Objs variable? Many thanks

Comment: `for obj in sel_Objs: obj.select_set(True)`

Comment: Perfect!
Thanks

Comment: You should store the obj.name instead bpy.types.Object,   because it can't access them after you do a undo. You also need check the object.name is it exist.